# Interactive graph of Europe using D3

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I need to create in D3 a chart like this:
[image]

A map of Europe (here is very simplified using squares instead of countries) whose countries are colored according to the number of deaths (caused by the choice disease) that have been selected in the year.

More color is dark and the greater the number of deaths (as described in the legend).

The user can choose the year that prefers using a slider and can choose the disease using a radio button.
According to the year and selected disease, the color change of the countries.

When the user rolls the mouse over a particular country (eg France), on the right appears some details like:

- the country
- year
- the number of total deaths
- the number of deaths divided by male and female

My dataset is done this way:

```
"","Country","Year","Sex","Death","Value"
"3","Austria","2012","Male","Tuberculosis",18
"4","Austria","2012","Male","Tetanus",1
"5","Austria","2012","Male","Diphtheria",0
"1641","Austria","2012","Female","Tuberculosis",7
"1642","Austria","2012","Female","Tetanus",0
"1643","Austria","2012","Female","Diphtheria",0
"3409","Austria","2011","Male","Tuberculosis",27
"3410","Austria","2011","Male","Tetanus",0
"3411","Austria","2011","Male","Diphtheria",0
"5047","Austria","2011","Female","Tuberculosis",14
"5048","Austria","2011","Female","Tetanus",0
"5049","Austria","2011","Female","Diphtheria",0
"46829","Austria","1998","Male","Tuberculosis",61
"46830","Austria","1998","Male","Tetanus",0
"46831","Austria","1998","Male","Diphtheria",0
"48341","Austria","1998","Female","Tuberculosis",30
"48342","Austria","1998","Female","Tetanus",0
"48343","Austria","1998","Female","Diphtheria",0
"59309","Belgium","2010","Male","Tuberculosis",13
"59310","Belgium","2010","Male","Tetanus",0
"59311","Belgium","2010","Male","Diphtheria",0
"60947","Belgium","2010","Female","Tuberculosis",13
"60948","Belgium","2010","Female","Tetanus",2
"60949","Belgium","2010","Female","Diphtheria",0
...
```

I searched if there were any similar graphics that I can use, but I found nothing.

I tried to create a map of Europe and this is what I got https://plnkr.co/edit/Ny0lUkVoiKeP76R95eVn?p=preview.

The chart does not work because it lacks the europe.json file. Plunker doesn't save becasue file is too large.
This is the [europe.json](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2gs4xtvv0sc3blr/europe.json?dl=0) files and this is what I see (if I pass the mouse over France):
[image]

In script.js file is a piece of code (commented) that does not work.
It is the first time I make graphics with maps.

Ok now I don't know where to begin.
How can I for example to associate the name of the country based on the country selected?
And to filter the data in the base year and the disease?
Could someone give me a hand?

I know I'm asking a lot, but I don't want all the code but a help to be able to move forward to develop the graph.

Thanks so much

---

I almost finished the chart, there are only two things that I can't fix: the legend and the color of the countries that doesn't change with the selected year.

Here the code: [**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/un7lYuZSWdL9A2vH38mK?p=preview)

For the legend I used the [library of Susie Lu](http://d3-legend.susielu.com/). 
The legend is created but not colored. I tried to change the range and use the same I used to color the countries but doesn't work.

```
// to color countries
var colors = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 1, 2300]) 
    .range(["#cccccc","#131313", "#ba3c28"]);
/**
 * Legend.
 */
var quantize = d3.scale.quantize()
    .domain([0, 1, 2300])
    //.range(["#cccccc","#131313", "#ba3c28"]);
    .range(d3.range(10).map(function(i) { 
        return "q" + i + "-10"; 
    }));

var svg = d3.select("#leftDown")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("class", "legendQuantsvg");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "legendQuant")
    .attr("transform", "translate(20, 20)");

var legend = d3.legend.color()
    .labelFormat(d3.format(".0f"))
    .useClass(true)
    .scale(quantize);

svg.select(".legendQuant")
    .call(legend);
```

The second problem is that if the user changes the year using the slider, the color of the countries does not change. 
I don't understand how to update the value of the slider.
In the right the data are taken correctly.

Could someone help me?

PS: I don't know if I was right to change this question or if I had to open another.
Anyway, thanks.

Comment: First at all: do not use json, instead use .topojson. It's .json map oriented optimized for web and has 10% of size. Use this page to translate from json to topojson: http://geojson.io load you file and save as TopoJSON

Comment: Your dataset has wrong header definition, assign any name to the first column, i.e.: id. "id","Country","Year","Sex","Death","Value"

Comment: please, join this room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113858/interactive-map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a complete solution to your answer, but gives you a general pattern I use.

- Set initial values, prepare the scenario for interface
- Call for data to server and wait for it arrives
- Draw map base, add event listener to interact with the user
- Filter and select the apropiate info depending on user action

**Set initial values, prepare the scenario for interface**

Load scripts

```
    <script src="js/d3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>      D3 base
    <script src="js/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>         TopoJSON
    <script src="js/d3-queue.v2.min.js"></script>         Queue
    <script src="js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>        jQuery
```

HTML

```
<div id="selector">
<form id="desses">
  <input type="radio" name="desse" value="tuberculosis" checked>Tuberculosis<br>
  <input type="radio" name="desse" value="tetanus">Tetanus<br>
  <input type="radio" name="desse" value="diphtheria">Diphtheria
</form>
</div>
<input type="range" id="rango" value="2014" min=2004 max=2014>
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="info"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
// width and height
var w = 800, h = 600, dess;

// define map projection
var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
    .center([13, 52])
    .translate([w/2, h/2])
    .scale([w/1.5]);

// define path generator
var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

// create SVG
var svg = d3.select("#container")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

var div = d3.select("body").append("div")   
    .attr("class", "tooltip")               
    .style("opacity", 0);
```

Must-read: [Let’s Make a Map](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/)

**Call for data to server and wait for it arrives**
You must wait for all data or user could start interact with some of them and get error, undefined values and so on.

Recomendation: separate your Map base from your data. You can change map and/or data without recreate all your json over and over again. Easy to mantain

```
d3_queue.queue()
    .defer(d3.json, 'data/europe.topojson')  //<-- Topojson base map
    .defer(d3.csv, 'data/dessease.csv')      //<-- dessease csv data
    .awaitAll(makemap);       // <-- When data arrives call makemap function
```

Must-Read: [Queue](http://bl.ocks.org/mapsam/6090056)

**Draw map base, add event listener to interact with the user**
Draw map. Add event listener **on** "mouseover" and "mouseout":

```
function makemap(error, europe, dessease) {
    dess = dessease.slice()
    counties = topojson.feature(europe, europe.objects.collection);
    vector = svg.selectAll("path")
        .data(counties.features)
      .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "county")
        .attr("id", function(d){ 
              return "coun"+d.properties.indx})
        .attr("d", path)
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {
            d3.select("#coun"+d.properties.indx).style('stroke', '777').style("stroke-width",2)
            showInfo(d)
        })
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {
            d3.select("#coun"+d.properties.indx).style('stroke', 'ddd').style("stroke-width",1)
            $("#info").html("")
        })      
};
```

Must-Read: [TopoJSON](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/API-Reference)

Tools: [TopoJSON Maps](https://geojson-maps.kyd.com.au) - [Letfleat map tool](http://geojson.io)

**Filter and select the apropiate info depending on user action**
You have two type interaction:

- user over a country (showInfo function)
- user select desseas or year (update function)

Javascript

```
var showInfo = function (d) {                    // Populate the tooltip
    var infoNest = d3.nest()
          .key(function(d) { return d.Year })    //<-- Filter selectors
          .key(function(d) { return d.Sex; })    //    Now you use
          .map(dess);                            //<-- your csv data
    $("#info").html($("#rango").val() + " - "+d.properties.name+" : "+JSON.stringify(infoNest['1998']['Male']) )   // sample
}
var update = function () {                       // change map color based on values
    var des = $('input[name=desse]:checked', '#desses').val(); 
    $("#info").html($("#rango").val()+ " : " + des) 
}
$('#desses').on('change', update);
$("#rango").on("input", update);
```

**d3.nest()** it's one of the most powerfull function of D3 to deal with data and subset of data.

Must-Read: [Groupin Data](http://learnjsdata.com/group_data.html) - [Arrays API](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Arrays) - [D3 using nest on csv data](http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/3176159) - [Reading in Data](http://learnjsdata.com/read_data.html)

Tools: [Mister Nester](http://bl.ocks.org/shancarter/raw/4748131/)

**PS:**

I've changed your .csv adding a column to bind .topojson country code to .csv:

```
indx,id,Country,Year,Sex,Death,Value
4,3,Austria,2012,Male,Tuberculosis,18
4,4,Austria,2012,Male,Tetanus,1
4,5,Austria,2012,Male,Diphtheria,0
4,1641,Austria,2012,Female,Tuberculosis,7
4,1642,Austria,2012,Female,Tetanus,0
4,1643,Austria,2012,Female,Diphtheria,0
4,3409,Austria,2011,Male,Tuberculosis,27
4,3410,Austria,2011,Male,Tetanus,0
4,3411,Austria,2011,Male,Diphtheria,0
4,5047,Austria,2011,Female,Tuberculosis,14
4,5048,Austria,2011,Female,Tetanus,0
4,5049,Austria,2011,Female,Diphtheria,0
4,46829,Austria,1998,Male,Tuberculosis,61
4,46830,Austria,1998,Male,Tetanus,0
4,46831,Austria,1998,Male,Diphtheria,0
4,48341,Austria,1998,Female,Tuberculosis,30
4,48342,Austria,1998,Female,Tetanus,0
4,48343,Austria,1998,Female,Diphtheria,0
2,59309,Belgium,2010,Male,Tuberculosis,13
2,59310,Belgium,2010,Male,Tetanus,0
2,59311,Belgium,2010,Male,Diphtheria,0
2,60947,Belgium,2010,Female,Tuberculosis,13
2,60948,Belgium,2010,Female,Tetanus,2
2,60949,Belgium,2010,Female,Diphtheria,0
```

each country has a code (indx), so when you select a country pass the code to filter data from csv.

Comment: I understand (not all) how it works and I'm trying to modify the code to suit my needs.
I'm trying to show the text (contained in div `#info`) taken from csv only when the mouse passes over a country. If the mouse is not on the country I would like that the text is not displayed.
How can I do that? I tried to create a boolean to false that becomes true inside the `showInfo` "method". But it does'tt work. It is a couple of hours that I try but I can't find a solution. Could you help (again)?

Comment: Just add: $("#info").html("") on event mouse out:         .on("mouseout", function(d) {
            d3.select("#coun"+d.properties.indx).style('stroke', 'ddd').style("stroke-width",1)
            $("#info").html("")
        })

Comment: Hey, I update my main message with some "little" problem. Can you help me? Thanks a lot

Comment: Firts all ... wooow ... your map its so cool, great job. I've made a simple map using rango o radio: https://plnkr.co/edit/5meAONB9eFUoFrJo7QWJ?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad you like it :) Ok, now the second problem is solved (thanks a lot). There remains the problem of legend..

Comment: I've never used Susie's lib. It's nice, but I can't find on her site how to define the color. The true is: she don't define colors, just rect with a class plus a legend. Like so: <rect class="swatch q0-10" height="15" width="15"></rect>. You must define the color for each quantile class. I've added a 'color.css' to your plnkr, here's the result: https://plnkr.co/edit/fEGDy3ssqasxE9KLz1oa?p=preview

Take a look at this: http://colorbrewer2.org you can generate a .js or .css for scales with the shape: 'qx-y'

Comment: Mmm better, but so the legend does not make much sense, the colors should be the same as I used to color the countries (`colors`)..

Comment: Yeah. You must tweak the rgb values to match your own scale

Comment: Yes, of course. I've read [this article](http://www.jeromecukier.net/blog/2011/08/11/d3-scales-and-color/). I'm looking for a way to find the intervals created by `colors`, in such a way that it can also use them for the legend. Something like `[0,230] = "#ffffff", [230,460] = "# e9e9e9"`, etc. There's a way?

Comment: Yes. Just use the previous function color you've created, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/r7qoy9vm/  you give the colors function a value and it return the color code, based on domain-range