# Coloring a map using D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to StackOverflow and I just started using D3.
I need to show the values on a map. I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37635547/interactive-graph-of-europe-using-d3/37644652?noredirect=1#comment63001871_37644652) that is very similar to what I should do.

What I'd like is to color the countries based on the values in the column `Date` to a CSV and based on selected year by user (radio button).
How can I do that?

I created a gray color scale and have included them in an array, then I created a method `chooseColor(value)` that returns the correct color based on the value of the country in that year.
I think it is not the most efficient method to do this thing...

Also in my CSV there are not all the countries present in the European Union. For example, I have no data on Russia so I "turned off" some countries putting an `if` inside the event on `mouseover`.
But I would also cut part of Russia in the map in order to enlarge the known countries. How can I do also that thing?

I looked at these examples: *Choropleth* and *Threshold Choropleth* by Mike Bostock on bl.ocks.org but I have not understand how to color the countries...
(I wanted to put links but I can't post more than 2 links because of my low reputation)

[This is my code](https://plnkr.co/edit/F4byFugwvnflH4S46295?p=preview).

I apologize for my bad English. Thank you all,

Pier

**EDIT**

I admit I did not understand some things in your code.

1. Why I need events `on mouseover` and `mouseout`? And what are `hover` and `rhover`? I thought they were events related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37635547/interactive-graph-of-europe-using-d3/37644652?noredirect=1#comment63001871_37644652). But in my case I don't need it, no?
2. Use `array_values` or `d` is the same, right? Does not change if I use `d` or `array_values`, right? It is a stupid question but it confused me.
3. I modified the `makemap` method in this way. I understand correctly how to use your code?

   function makemap(error, europe, dessease) {
       dess = dessease.slice();
       counties = topojson.feature(europe, europe.objects.collection);

   ```
   vector = svg.selectAll("path")
       .data(counties.features)
       .enter()
       .append("path")
       .attr("class", "county")
       .attr("id", function(d) { 
           return "coun" + d.properties.indx;
       })
       .attr("d", path)
       .style("fill", function(array_values) {
           return color(array_values[d.country]);
       });
   ```

In this case there is an error concerning `d`, of course. Sorry, I do not know where I'm wrong...

Comment: Please Delete your function: chooseColor. Or refactor it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The country's color will depend on a value. So the color IS a function of "value". To do that you must to define a range of color based on your values:

```
var color = d3.scale.linear()
                      .domain([mn,mx])      // <--- min and MAX of your value
                      .range(["#ffffff","000000"]);
```

then define the color of your country:

```
svg.selectAll(".county")
                  .style("fill", function(array_values) {
                        return color(array_values[d.country]);
                  });
```

Must-Read: [Jerome Cukier - d3: scales, and color](http://www.jeromecukier.net/blog/2011/08/11/d3-scales-and-color/)

Comment: I modified the code as you suggested but it doesn't work. Now the countries are all blacks and not grayscale based on values. Why? [code](https://plnkr.co/edit/F4byFugwvnflH4S46295?p=preview)

Comment: Check your [min, MAX] of your values. Is it d.value the correct?

Comment: `[min, max]` is correct but if I print `d.value` I get `undefined`..Am I wrong to take the values from the csv file?

Comment: No. At this point d has the topojson values, your are inside the selection: .selectAll("path"). You must referenciate to dess array, it has the desseses values (from csv) or what you trying to represent

Comment: Probably I'm wrong where to insert the code. I put the code `svg.selectAll(".county")
  .style("fill", function(d) {
   console.log(d.value);
     return color(+d.value);
  });` after `vector = svg.selectAll("path")
  ...
  .on("mouseout", function(d) {
   ...
  });`. Or it is `undefined` because it depends on the `year`? Sorry but I don't understand...

Comment: No problem. on mouse over give you (d) the country were you're on. So you has the country, now you must get the value of the year for this country from .cvs. Here's were .indx come helpful. .indx it's present on both files (.csv and .topojson) let you bind the country with the data on your .csv. On this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37635547/interactive-graph-of-europe-using-d3/37644652. The values from .cvs are stored on 'dess' array. Look at the bottom to get an idea whats .indx it's.

Comment: I have not solved the problem yet. Can you help me? Thanks a lot, Pier

Comment: Ok. Let me check to give you a complete solution :)

Comment: Hey .. I've made a new Plunker, you can see it here: https://plnkr.co/edit/4EMvdDxfjsnYzXWmi1p2?p=preview